# How would I "iterate" through a range of numbers?

Tags: haskell, iteration, range

Let's say my function (`foo`) takes 2 arguments: `startNum`, and `endNum`. I need to return every single a list of every multiple of 2 (or alternatively, every number evenly divisible by 2) that falls within that range by checking each number one by one. It is assumed that `endNum` will always be greater than `startNum`.

For example, if the function signature was something like this:
`foo :: Int -> Int -> Int[]`

Then `foo(5,10)` would return `[6, 8, 10]`.

So far I have tried to mimic a "for" loop, and attempted to use `map` and `scan/scanl` in slightly unconventional ways to try and account for the fact that I am not starting off with a list, but rather a range of numbers. However, I have not been able to find a solution using these methods (my level of experience with Haskell is very low, so that is the biggest factor here in why I have not been able to accomplish so simple of a task).

I am expecting the solution, in some way, to use recursion. I am not sure exactly how to begin an implementation of this, or if my previously attempted methods are even correct ways to go about it.

Comment: “my level of experience with Haskell is very low” – well, honestly, you should read at least some basic tutorials before asking questions on StackOverflow, then. FTR, the idiomatic solution doesn't require any iteration or recursion or whatever but just `foo lb ub = filter even [lb..ub]`, that's all. But, this is not very instructive. Sure, we could now explain a lot of different ways this problem could be tackled and what goes on under the hood and make a tutorial out of that... but this isn't really what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: ...And if you do ask a question, make sure to include your own attempts, this makes it much better answerable.

Comment: what about `[i | i <-[startNum .. endNum], even i]`?. This solution is completely equivalent to python's `[i for i in range(startNum , endNum) if even(i)]`. Moreover, this example is in page 67 of `Learn you a Haskell for grater good`. If you are going to ask very basic questions, be sure you have done an effort researching by yourself. It is very frustrating when OPs seem to not making an effort at all.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration in Haskell usually means either recursion, or a list comprehension.

For recursion you need a base case and an update case. In your example, we know that if `startNum` is greater than `endNum`, the list must be empty. That's easy to write:

```
foo startNum endNum
  | startNum > endNum = []
```

The trick is the update. Or *updates*. What do you return if `startNum` is even? What about when it's not?

```
foo startNum endNum
  | startNum > endNum = []
  | even startNum     = ...
  | otherwise         = ...
```

More natural is a list comprehension with a condition. That code is trivial.

```
[x | x <- [startNum..endNum], even x]
```